# *Google Sheets-GAS* How do I sort three numbers in smallest to largest order then return each number to an individual cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am learning Google App Script with Google Sheets and having a hard time finding examples of this task. How do I sort these three numbers in the row and return them to the same three cells but sorted smallest to largest?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dhEocIG5TS94ZyU5o8QRn2-urg0SqJdZ7piinAe5WA8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in particular show us your coding attempts and what is not working.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't have a coding attempt. When I start on this function I realize I don't even know how to use the syntax to get the range specific to those cells. I thought maybe I could  set the formula or something and go that route.  So I guess part of my problem is choosing an approach. If you know a place with example code with these sorts of problems in GAS. I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Zig is entirely correct in his comment, this should work with your current set of data;

```
function sort() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var values = ss.getRange('A1:C').getValues()
    .map(function (r) {
        return r.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        });
    })
ss.getRange('A1:C').setValues(values)
}
```

Comment: So I just found the sort method in the reference but where did the .map come from?

Comment: .map() is a javascript method that creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map